# Is there a place to land a private plane in or near Virginia City NV?

Tags: landing

Is there a place to land  a private plane in or near Virginia City NV?

Answer (score 3):

https://skyvector.com/ is kinda a "Google Maps" for airports and routes.

[This Map](https://skyvector.com/?ll=39.296978153045075,-119.53989743814515&chart=301&zoom=1&fpl=%20A34%20undefined) shows Virginia City is roughly equidistant between [Dayton Valley Airpark](https://skyvector.com/airport/A34/Dayton-Valley-Airpark-Airport), [Carson City](https://skyvector.com/airport/CXP/Carson-City-Airport) and [Reno/Tahoe International](https://skyvector.com/airport/RNO/Reno-Tahoe-International-Airport)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typing "airfield locator" in Google pointed me to https://www.airnav.com/airports/search.html or https://landingfinder.com (but there are probably dozens if not hundreds of alternatives) which in turn both pointed me to Dayton Valley Airpark, 7 miles away (and a number of other alternatives).